# Finding the matching struct field type to string

Tags: go

Here is the code:

```
type OrderSide string

const (
    OrderSideSell OrderSide = "SELL"
    OrderSideBuy  OrderSide = "BUY"
)

type orderSides struct {
    Sell OrderSide
    Buy  OrderSide
}

var (
    OrderSides orderSides = orderSides{
        Sell: OrderSideSell,
        Buy:  OrderSideBuy,
    }
)
```

Now, I'd like to be able to convert between a `string` and an OrderSide (or better yet, an `OrderSides` field). In other words, given a `string` containing either `"SELL"` or `"BUY"`, how do I return the corresponding `OrderSide` constant (or `OrderSides.<>` field).

To be clear, the objective here is to do this dynamically, so that I don't need to implement a giant switch where I add cases as I add additional OrderSide fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since OrderSide is just an alias for a string, the easiest way to convert from string to OrderSide is: `anOrderSide = OrderSide(aString)`.

Here's a longer example of ways to create OrderSides or get them from string variables([Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/GyR_G0fCTCb)):

```
type OrderSide string

func main() {
    var anOrderSide OrderSide
    anOrderSide = "def"

    fmt.Println(anOrderSide)
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(anOrderSide))

    var aString string
    var anotherOrderSide OrderSide

    aString = "abc"

    anotherOrderSide = OrderSide(aString)

    fmt.Println(aString)
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(aString))
    fmt.Println(anotherOrderSide)
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(anotherOrderSide))
}
```

This doesn't check that your string is a valid OrderSide according to your "enum." You will need to validate that the strings are in the list of valid OrderSides elsewhere. An easy way would be to create a map with the keys being all the valid string values for OrderSides and the values being empty struct:

```
validOrderSides := make(map[string]struct{})

validOrderSides["BUY"] = struct{}{}
validOrderSides["SELL"] = struct{}{}
```

Then you can just check if the string you plan to convert is in the map: `_, ok := validOrderSides["BUY"]`.

Or if you prefer, you can make it a `map[string]OrderSide` and convert from string to OrderSide and validate at the same time: `orderSide, isValid := stringToOrderSide["BUY"]`.

Comment: What will happen if I do not validate the string prior to assigning it? a runtime error?

Comment: No error. `OrderSide` is just an alias for `string` - so any `string` is valid for conversion to `OrderSide`.  (Even something like `OrderSide("")` will not raise any error.) However, depending on how you handle OrderSides which aren't in the "enum" you may run into problems with your business logic.